# Auto generation of predicates and accessors for discriminated unions in F#

Tags: f#, algebraic-data-types, discriminated-union

Is it possible in F# to automatically generate predicates and accessors for an arbitrary algebraic data type in type-safe manner?

For example, if we have user defined type:

```
type A = 
    B of string
    | C of int * sting
```

should be generated something like this:

```
type A = 
    B of string
    | C of int * sting
    with
        member __.isB = match __ with B -> true | _ -> false
        member __.isC = match __ with C -> true | _ -> false
        member __._1 = match __ with B(x) -> Some(x) | _ -> None
        member __._2 = match __ with C(x,_) -> Some(x) | _ -> None
        member __._3 = match __ with C(_,x) -> Some(x) | _ -> None
```

It will be better if can specify names for accessors may be with annotation like this:

```
[<GenerateAccessors(["BName", "CName", "Value"])>]
```

May be it can not be done or I should use records instead discriminated unions (DU) if I want to siplify access to inner data. But it's more simply to use patten matching with DUs and I want both of this profits - simply pattern matching and simply "direct data access" - in the same time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want this?

Answer (score 2):

You can reflect over a discriminated union using [FSharpType.GetUnionCases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353736.aspx) and generate code using the F# CodeDOM available in the [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) or simply by writing text.

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

type A = B of string | C of int * string

let generate t =
    let cases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases(t)
    printfn "type %s with" t.Name
    for case in cases do
        printfn "\tmember value.is%s = " case.Name
        let fields = 
            match [for field in case.GetFields() -> "_"] with
            | [] -> ""
            | fields -> " (" + (fields |> String.concat ",") + ")"
        printfn "\t\tmatch value with %s%s -> true | _ -> false" case.Name fields

generate typeof<A>
```

Generates an [F# type extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233211.aspx):

```
type A with
    member value.isB =
        match value with B (_) -> true | _ -> false
    member value.isC =
        match value with C (_,_) -> true | _ -> false
```